# MATLAB: Copying Global variable for all Workers

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I want to pass "a" as a global variable to the function "tsfn", say

```
function [ out ] = tsfn(  )

   global a;
   out=a+1;

end
```

When I run the following I get the expected result:

```
>> global a;
a=1

out=[];
for i=1:4
   out =[out tsfn()];
end

out

a =

    1
out =

    2     2     2     2
```

However if I run it with parfor instead of for I end up with a blank vector. Which leads me to believe that "a" is not being passed into the function. I'm wondering if there is a way to pass the variable as a global variable for all workers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Works fine on my platform. Try just restarting your computer or Matlab. Generally, the "parfor" loop accomplishes the same task as the "for" loop--each loop is computed in parallel. Declaring "global" in one or more functions and/or the base workspace allows each of them to access the contents of the global variable, so your usage is correct.

Here is my code:

```
function[ out ] = tsfn()

     global a;
     out = a + 1;

end

EDU>> global a;
EDU>> a = 1;
EDU>> out = [];
EDU>> parfor i = 1 : 4
          out = [ out tsfn() ];
      end
EDU>> a

a =

     1

EDU>> out

out =

     2     2     2     2
```

Aside, a simple way to test the contents of a variable inside a function is to remove the semicolon, which prints it to the editor.